# Is there a shortcut to hide the find widget in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can open the find in page widget by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but pressing it again only focuses it.

I really dislike having to use my mouse to get rid of the find widget as it blocks out some of the code.

Anyone know how to use a shortcut to hide the find widget?

[image: Find Widget]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key work for this?

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks!

Comment: Of course `ESC` does that, but problem is that you have to 'focus' on the widget by clicking it (or pressing cmd+f (mac)).

Answer (score 7):

You can make it toggle by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Just add this to [keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "closeFindWidget",
    "when": "editorFocus && findWidgetVisible"
}
```