How to exclude selecting headers in a file when ctrl a select all or ctrl home go to beginning of a file in vscode?
How to exclude selecting headers in a file when ctrl a select all or ctrl home go to beginning of a file in vscode?
eg:
Given a markdown file
<link href='G:/Using/mdCss/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='./style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<!-- some random header info -->

This is the content.
Some random sentences.

Current behavior:
press ctrl a
you select all of the lines.
Expected behavior:
Do some configuration.
eg: put a comment as separator.
<link href='G:/Using/mdCss/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='./style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<!-- some random header info -->
<!-- ctrl a dont select above -->

This is the content.
Some random sentences.

press ctrl a
you will only select:
This is the content.
Some random sentences.

In other words, I want to have a keybinding to select everything in a file except some starting lines that terminate with a well-known string.
Is it possible?

Same logic for ctrl home.
Not just for md, also for html, or other programming languages.


Sorry, your request is not sensible.  Those are not "headers" in any definition of the word.  Markdown can and often does include HTML tags.  Ctrl-A means "select ALL".

@TimRoberts Yes, I understand that, but is there a way to assign a new command or hotkey for my special behavior? \ For the terminology "header" I cant find a better word to describe it (I can only think of tampermonkey / UserCss use that terminology for "special text at the beginning of the file").

Select All does exactly that - it selects ALL. There is no key mapping available for Select All except this part. Likewise, Ctrl+Home takes you to the TOP of the file. There is no key mapping for Take me to the top, but by top I mean below this section.

@KenWhite Yes, I understand what those key does & what they mean. What I am trying to here is to find a solution for my use case.  \ Maybe an extension or something that does these kind of jobs. \ Or some config, eg: tweak the "ctrl home" to something like "goto line". \ Or, eg: tweak the "ctrl a" to behave like "alt shift right to smart expand select" \ -- those things are totally doable, Im just trying to find a way. \ Or, like ipynb files, they knows how to render a cell as a block, where you "ctrl a" only select the cell.

You can use a regex to select only what you want.  See regex101 demo.
Find: ^(?!(<link|<!--)).+$
Explanation: Match lines that do not start with <link or <!--.  You can see that it is just an alternation (or) of line starters, like <link that could easily modify yourself to add other line starters to avoid or remove the <!-- if you do not need that.
Now assuming you want to reuse this you don't want to have to paste that regex into the Find Widget every time.  We can set up a keybinding to automate this.  Put this into your keybindings.json:
{
  "key": "alt+f", // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
  "args": {
    "searchString": "^(?!(<link|<!--)).+$",
    "isRegex": true
  }
}

See my answer at Perform pre-defined Find-Replace-All in VSCode using a keybinding for the other options to this command.
Triggering that keybinding will open the Find Widget, populate it with your regex and options.  Then you can Alt+Enter (the command editor.action.selectAllMatches) to select the matches - whether your focus is in the Find Widget or the file.
If you want you can automate this further by combining the two commands into one keybinding using the runCommands command:
{
  "key": "alt+f", // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
        "args": {
          "searchString": "^(?!(<link|<!--)).+$",
          "isRegex": true
        }
      },
      "editor.action.selectAllMatches",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"    // to trigger copy to clipboard
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == markdown"
}



This is a more completed version.
Doesnt seem like its possible to use other flags inside the regex like m / s .
To close the find widget after the selection
closeFindWidget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535964/is-there-a-shortcut-to-hide-the-find-widget-in-vs-code
(No docs for this in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands )
To reset the find flags, re-execute the findWithArgs with flags you prefer as default.


Put this in keybindings.json:
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
    "args": {
        "isRegex": true,
        "isCaseSensitive": true,
        "findInSelection": false,
        "searchString": "(?<=<!-- some random header info -->\\n)([\\n\\s]|.)*",
    },
},

See also:

Perform pre-defined Find-Replace-All in VSCode using a keybinding
Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups
Multiline regular expression search in Visual Studio Code


(Thats a smart and simple way)

Why is this using runCommands?  It is only running one command.  And how does this help select the 'non-header' text the OP wants?

@Mark it (was) using runCommands because when I started writing it I assumed I might need it, and then I forgot to remove it after testing.
